pgloader failing when attempting to migrate from mysql
I have a laptop with ubuntu installed
john@John-Ubuntu:~$ uname -a
Linux John-Ubuntu 6.8.0-49-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Nov  4 02:06:24 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I have pgloader installed
john@John-Ubuntu:~$ pgloader -V
pgloader version "3.6.7~devel"
compiled with SBCL 2.2.9.debian
john@John-Ubuntu:~$

I execute the following pgloader command
pgloader --verbose --debug mysql://john:MYPASSWORD@localhost/dbs1106047  postgresql:///test

the output:
pgloader version 4.6.7~devel
compiled with SBCL 2.2.9.debian
sb-impl::*default-external-format* :UTF-8
tmpdir: #P"/tmp/pgloader/"
2024-11-25T12:06:27.029000Z NOTICE Starting pgloader, log system is ready.
2024-11-25T12:06:27.045999Z INFO Starting monitor
2024-11-25T12:06:27.053999Z LOG pgloader version "3.6.7~devel"
2024-11-25T12:06:27.054999Z INFO     SOURCE: "mysql://john:MYPASSWORD@localhost/dbs1106047"
2024-11-25T12:06:27.055999Z INFO SOURCE URI: #<PGLOADER.SOURCE.MYSQL:MYSQL-CONNECTION mysql://john@localhost:3306/dbs1106047 {1005DCBCF3}>
2024-11-25T12:06:27.055999Z INFO     TARGET: "postgresql:///test"
2024-11-25T12:06:27.055999Z INFO TARGET URI: #<PGLOADER.PGSQL:PGSQL-CONNECTION pgsql://john@UNIX:5432/test {1005F97933}>
2024-11-25T12:06:27.055999Z DEBUG LOAD DATA FROM #<PGLOADER.SOURCE.MYSQL:MYSQL-CONNECTION mysql://john@localhost:3306/dbs1106047 {1005DCBCF3}>
2024-11-25T12:06:27.121999Z DEBUG CONNECTED TO #<PGLOADER.PGSQL:PGSQL-CONNECTION pgsql://john@UNIX:5432/test {1005F97933}>
2024-11-25T12:06:27.121999Z DEBUG SET client_encoding TO 'utf8'
2024-11-25T12:06:27.121999Z DEBUG SET application_name TO 'pgloader'
2024-11-25T12:06:27.166998Z LOG Migrating from #<MYSQL-CONNECTION mysql://john@localhost:3306/dbs1106047 {1005DCBCF3}>
2024-11-25T12:06:27.166998Z LOG Migrating into #<PGSQL-CONNECTION pgsql://john@UNIX:5432/test {1005F97933}>
2024-11-25T12:06:27.253998Z DEBUG CONNECTED TO #<MYSQL-CONNECTION mysql://john@localhost:3306/dbs1106047 {1005DCBCF3}>
2024-11-25T12:06:27.264998Z SQL MySQL: sending query: -- params: db-name
--         table-type-name
--         only-tables
--         only-tables
--         including
--         filter-list-to-where-clause incuding
--         excluding
--         filter-list-to-where-clause excluding
  select c.table_name, t.table_comment,
         c.column_name, c.column_comment,
         c.data_type, c.column_type, c.column_default,
         c.is_nullable, c.extra
    from information_schema.columns c
         join information_schema.tables t using(table_schema, table_name)
   where c.table_schema = 'dbs1106047' and t.table_type = 'BASE TABLE'


order by table_name, ordinal_position;
2024-11-25T12:06:27.309997Z ERROR mysql: 76 fell through ECASE expression.
       Wanted one of (2 3 4 5 6 8 9 10 11 14 15 17 20 21 23 27 28 30 31 32 33
                      35 41 42 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 54 55 56 60 61 62 63 64
                      65 69 72 77 78 79 82 83 87 90 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 101
                      102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115
                      116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 128 129 130 131 132
                      133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146
                      147 148 149 150 151 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167
                      168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 181
                      182 183 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200 201 202 203
                      204 205 206 207 208 209 210 211 212 213 214 215 223 224
                      225 226 227 228 229 230 231 232 233 234 235 236 237 238
                      239 240 241 242 243 244 245 246 247 254).
2024-11-25T12:06:27.309997Z LOG report summary reset
       table name     errors       read   imported      bytes      total time       read      write
-----------------  ---------  ---------  ---------  ---------  --------------  ---------  ---------
  fetch meta data          0          0          0                     0.000s
-----------------  ---------  ---------  ---------  ---------  --------------  ---------  ---------
-----------------  ---------  ---------  ---------  ---------  --------------  ---------  ---------
2024-11-25T12:06:27.363997Z INFO Stopping monitor

I have searched the net but not managed to find a way to resolve any help would be much appreciated.

That looks like this issue ECASE error for utf8mb4_0900_xx #913 - I don't see pgloader version "3.6.7~devel" in the official Ubuntu repos, how did you install it?

You've not said what Ubuntu product & release; you give kernel details (uname gives kernel details only) which show a kernel that is used by multiple releases.  Please be specific with details, what Ubuntu release are you using?
